# Most optimum way to use ice on long corridors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been working on a survival map for a while, and right yesterday got my ice farm.

So the fact is that I want to use this ice to move faster between portals in nether, but also at some places in overworld.

My corridors are 2*2, but I have to hold me to use everything as packed ice because it will take for ages for me to fill those corridors, even if I do it in 1 side of the 2 they have.

So how do I have to difference between packed ice and normal ice at nether and overworld? Do trap doors help when holding light away from ice blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice is usually not used for iceways as it melts, you should try other non-melting variants like blue or packed ice.

---

If you are in late game and still want to use ice(for looks?) you could have perpetually bouncing armor stands with frost walker along the ice to turn it into ice again and again(but this is not efficient) for the overworld. No easy solution for the nether though.

---

Maybe you should just find the variants if you do not want to keep the iceway pitch black. Find a biome here chunkbase.com/

---

As for the trapdoors, they are used for better jump sprinting in corridor, as they break your jump faster than only full blocks, whereas a half slab does not let you jump(I suppose thats why you mention trapdoors-from tutorials).

Good luck on your adventures in survival!

Comment: As i can understand from your answer, ice in all of its variants may not be the best way to do what I want to do. I want to get to the point where i can move myself as fast as possible between portals in my nether hub. Anyhow I'm obviously taking the safest and resource friendly solution, as I've fallen myself to death many times. At this point, and by the time it takes to gather that much ice for me (Not that good farm), I have to make a choice between making a really big afk ice farm, which at this point is really hard for me, or change the system, even though I move a bit slower...

Comment: If you have a rail duper, plenty of pistons and redstone, the fastest way to travel would be by piston 'Bolts'. Illmango (YouTuber)  has a good video on this. Sprint running with trapdoors on top are sufficiently fast to get anywhere, short of the world border.

Comment: Your link currently goes to [diy.se]. I don't think that's intentional (unless I'm missing out on a really odd joke).

Comment: @Ulukai Nope, my mistake! Thanks for informing me, i've made the necessary edits

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a difference really, but one important fact: **Ice melts**.

While it is completely safe to use packed ice you'll have more trouble using normal ice. When exposed to a light source other than sunlight (> 11) normal ice will melt. Packed ice doesn't.

In the Nether ice does not turn into water (they fixed that), so if it melts there it's just gone. In the overworld it will still turn into water, if there's a block underneath it. Also packed ice is a solid block and mobs can spawn on it (but as of 1.13 polar bears can spawn on normal ice as well [[source]](https://minecraft.wiki/w/18w19a)).

And finally: if you want the best speed effect, use [blue ice](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blue_Ice). It's more slippery than the other two forms of ice.

Comment: Thank you! Is it that worthy to go for blue ice? For late game at least, and what's about trapdoors, do they block light for the ice to not get melt??

Comment: @Marcos'HaddocK'Pérez blue ice makes it faster, but if its worth it is up to you. And [trapdoors don't block light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98145/do-doors-and-trapdoors-block-light). But if you're using packed or blue ice it doesn't matter anyway. They both don't melt.